# What does "mother father gentleman" mean?

Tags: meaning

How should I interpret the phrase "mother father gentleman" in a recently popularized [song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASO_zypdnsQ) entitled *gentleman*? What is the purpose of describing *gentleman* with *mother* and *father*? Is this just a slang expression from the pop culture? I've seen many teenagers started using this phrase in sentences like "I'm mother father gentleman LOL".

Comment: [It means I don't ever have to work again if I don't want to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Pie_(song))

Answer (score 2):

It's a lyric from a pop song; it's not necessarily meant to be proper English, especially since it was written by a Korean singer.

Presumably we can infer that PSY meant for the phrase to sound like "mother-fucking gentleman", but by saying "father" instead of "fucking" he's indirectly saying that he's a gentleman who can relate to (and gain the approval of) the mother and father of his female love interest. (this is all tongue-in-cheek, since his behavior throughout the video is anything but gentlemanly)